# Mandrill API response with HTTP Status 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mandrill

I've been trying to get my MVC web app to send emails using a subscription with Mandrill API to no avail. This Mandrill API works by POSTing a `JSON` object to a specific endpoint. It looks pretty simple and straight-forward and that's why it's so frustrating that everytime I tried to send an email message I get an response from Mandrill with nothing more than a "500 Internal Server Error" no extra information or anything else.

Interestingly, Mandrill API has a [public test tool](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html) that you can use to test their API. So, I went in and passed exactly the same `JSON` object my application is sending when receiving that annoying Http Error and the email message is sent without any issues. So basically I have no problems sending the same email through their [Test Tool](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html) but it fails when my application attempts to send it.

Please find below the delegated to send the email message. It's not yet re-factored...sorry...

```
public bool Send(string to, string toDisplayName, string subject, string body)
{
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        try
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = string.Format(@"{{""key"": ""{0}"",""message"": {{""html"": ""{1}"",""subject"": ""{2}"",""from_email"": ""{3}"",""from_name"": ""AppCompear"",""to"": [{{""email"": ""{4}"",""name"": ""{5}"",""type"": ""to""}}],""important"": false}},""async"": false,""ip_pool"": ""Main Pool""}}"
                    , _setting.Password, body.Replace(@"""", @"\"""), subject, _setting.UserName, to, toDisplayName);

                LogManager.Current.LogError(to, "", "", "", null, json);
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            LogManager.Current.LogError(to, "", "", "", wex, wex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.Current.LogError(to, "", "", "", ex, ex.Message);
        }

        return true;
  }
```

And of course, it fails when trying to get the response

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after digging around Mandrill API docs in a search for clues on what needed to be taken into account to make an API call (it didn't seem to be that straight-forward) I decided to install a NuGet package that is actually a .NET wrapper around the Mandrill API.

After making some adjustments the code looked similar to the following...

```
Mandrill.EmailMessage message = new Mandrill.EmailMessage();
message.from_email = _setting.UserName;
message.from_name = "Whatever";
message.html = body;
message.subject = subject;
message.to = new List<Mandrill.EmailAddress>()
{
    new Mandrill.EmailAddress(to, toDisplayName)
};

Mandrill.MandrillApi mandrillApi = new Mandrill.MandrillApi(_setting.Password, false);
var results = mandrillApi.SendMessage(message);

foreach (var result in results)
{
      if (result.Status != Mandrill.EmailResultStatus.Sent)
           LogManager.Current.LogError(result.Email, "", "", "", null, string.Format("Email failed to send: {0}", result.RejectReason));
}
```

Comment: i added the Mandrill.API from nuget but cannot find the Mandrill.EmailMessage.. please advise?

Comment: @user384080 did you add a reference to the `Mandrill` namespace? `using Madrill;`